# Update grid w/ values returned from AJAX create call

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid which does AJAX edits to an MVC method.  The method returns a new copy of the grid row model with some calculations which are performed on the server.  Is there a way to update the grid with this data after the edit result is received?

Here's my grid code

```vb
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Of AssemblyPartListRowViewModel) _
        .Name("parts") _
        .ToolBar(Sub(toolbar)
                         toolbar.Create().Text("Add Part to Assembly")
                 End Sub) _
        .DataSource(Sub(config)
                            config _
                            .Ajax() _
                            .Events(Sub(events) events.Error("parts_Error")) _
                            .Model(Sub(model)
                                           model.Id(Function(x) x.AssemblyPartDefID)
                                           model.Field(Function(x) x.PartNumber)
                                           model.Field(Function(x) x.Description).Editable(False)
                                           model.Field(Function(x) x.Cost).Editable(False)
                                           model.Field(Function(x) x.ResaleValue).Editable(False)
                                           model.Field(Function(x) x.TotalResaleValue).Editable(False)
                                   End Sub) _
                            .Read("PartList", "Assembly", New With {.id = Model.AssemblyID}) _
                            .Destroy("RemovePart", "Assembly") _
                            .Create(Sub(create)
                                            create.Action("AddPart", "Assembly")
                                            create.Data("function() { return { assemblyId: " & Model.AssemblyID & " }; }")
                                    End Sub) _
                            .Update("UpdatePart", "Assembly")
                    End Sub) _
        .Columns(Sub(config)
                         config.Bound(Function(x) x.PartsQuantity).Width(20).Title("Quantity")
                         config.Bound(Function(x) x.PartNumber).Title("Part Number")
                         config.Bound(Function(x) x.Description).Title("Part Description")
                         config.Bound(Function(x) x.Cost).Format("{0:C}")
                         config.Bound(Function(x) x.ResaleValue).Title("Resale").Format("{0:C}")
                         config.Bound(Function(x) x.TotalResaleValue).Title("Line Total").Format("{0:C}")
                         config.Command(Sub(command)
                                                command.Destroy().Text("delete")
                                                command.Edit()
                                        End Sub)
                 End Sub)
    )
```

Here's the create method in my controller

```vb
    '
    ' POST: /Assembly/AddPart

    <HttpPost()> _
    Public Function AddPart(model As AssemblyPartListRowViewModel) As ActionResult
        Dim partDef As AssemblyPartDef = DataSource.AssemblyPartDefs.LoadNew(model)
        DataSource.SaveChanges()

        Return Json(GetAssemblyPartListModel(partDef))
    End Function
```

Comment: What does the update method on your dataSource look like ?

Comment: @giltnerj0 added code to original question